# python looping through elements of a list with While Loop using Boolean Expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

Guys I am trying to realise given input should loop through my float list named `enerji` and print out the first element if it is less than it and 1 before element of it. (edit y=82 in my case it is deffined above but not seen)
here is the code:

```
    a = 0
    input_bigger_than_energy = False
    while a!= y and not(input_bigger_than_energy):
        energy = float(input('write down interwal of energy between 1000 and 
    100000000000:'))
        if energy > enerji[a]:
            a=a+1
        else:
            input_bigger_than_energy = True
    print(a)
    print(enerji[a])
    print(enerji[a-1])



enerji = [1000.0, 1500.0, 1838.8, 1838.9, 2000.0, 3000.0, 4000.0, 5000.0, 6000.0, 8000.0, 10000.0, 15000.0, 20000.0, 30000.0, 40000.0, 50000.0, 60000.0, 80000.0, 100000.0, 150000.0, 200000.0, 300000.0, 400000.0, 500000.0, 600000.0, 800000.0, 1000000.0, 1022000.0, 1250000.0, 1500000.0, 2000000.0, 2044000.0, 3000000.0, 4000000.0, 5000000.0, 6000000.0, 7000000.0, 8000000.0, 9000000.0, 10000000.0, 11000000.0, 12000000.0, 13000000.0, 14000000.0, 15000000.0, 16000000.0, 18000000.0, 20000000.0, 22000000.0, 24000000.0, 26000000.0, 28000000.0, 30000000.0, 40000000.0, 50000000.0, 60000000.0, 80000000.0, 100000000.0, 150000000.0, 200000000.0, 300000000.0, 400000000.0, 500000000.0, 600000000.0, 800000000.0, 1000000000.0, 1500000000.0, 2000000000.0, 3000000000.0, 4000000000.0, 5000000000.0, 6000000000.0, 8000000000.0, 10000000000.0, 15000000000.0, 20000000000.0, 30000000000.0, 40000000000.0, 50000000000.0, 60000000000.0, 80000000000.0, 100000000000.0]
```

problem code works but it is asking me again to input

Comment: Can you reformat your code, or re-paste it?  It's hard to tell where your while loop begins and ends.  As for why you get asked for input again, my _guess_ is that you're missing a `break`.  Also, I don't see where `i` is defined at all.  In essence, your condition on the while loop isn't evaluating like you think it is.

Comment: my bad it should be 'a' instead of 'i' corrected it but still having the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the input statement inside the loop; it will ask for an input for every time it loops.

Also, the variable y is never set to a value.

```
# Shortened the list of example data
enerji = [1000.0, 1500.0, 1838.8, 1838.9, 2000.0, 3000.0, 4000.0]

a = 0
input_bigger_than_energy = False
y = 10  # Guessing a value for unknown variable

energy = float(input('write down interwal of energy between 1000 and 100000000000: '))
while a != y and not(input_bigger_than_energy):
    if energy > enerji[a]:
        a=a+1
    else:
        input_bigger_than_energy = True

print(a)
print(enerji[a])
print(enerji[a-1])
```